# JavaFX ListView howto select no cell

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am using this [cellFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23644379/4130107) here to get a `ListView` which has deselecable Cells.

But when I call `listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` and then click some other Node, everytime the first cell gets selected.

Debugging brought me to the `ListView.class` file to line 374 where the `InvalidationListener` is called and selects the first one.

Is it possible to somehow disable this Listener so that I can select no cell in my `ListView`?

Thanks!

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? If it's 8u25 or earlier, I think this is due to a bug; try upgrading to the latest version and see if that fixes it.

Comment: No I am using 8u40 due to the new MessageBoxes